# Hive views not reflecting base table changes

Tags: hive, hiveql, ambari, hiveddl

I have a number Views in Hive.  Most of the views were created using a pattern `select *` rather than specific column names.  When a column was removed from the base table, all these views started throwing `missing column` errors. I couldn't even do a `select * from myview`.

It appears that although my original view creation text is `select *`, Hive appear to have converted them into an extended format such as `select col1, col2, col3 etc`.

Is there a workaround or setting that I should enable, so that changes are reflected in views without needing to recreate them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hive is using stored view definitions.

In SQL:200n, a view definition is supposed to be frozen at the time it is created, so that if the view is defined as select * from t, where t is a table with two columns a and b, then later requests to select * from the view should return just columns a and b, even if a new column c is later added to the table. This is implemented correctly by most DBMS products. See more details in this design document: [Stored View Definition](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/ViewDev#ViewDev-StoredViewDefinition)

So, you need to perform `ALTER VIEW [db_name.]view_name AS select_statement;` command to reflect DDL changes. `Alter View As Select` changes the definition of a view, which must exist. The syntax is similar to that for `CREATE VIEW` and the effect is the same as for `CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW`. See more details here: [Alter View](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-Create/Drop/AlterView).